# align-middle question

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

What is my misunderstanding about the way that `vertical-align:middle;` works?

I have posted (http://jsfiddle.net/D6RwZ/) some code which I would expect to vertically align a red rectangle in a blue rectangle, but it doesn't look like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertical-align only works on inline images and display: table-cell.

I've used [this solution](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) a few times and it works quite well but takes some work. If you're working with fixed size elements position absolute is by far the simplest. Dynamic sized elements and vertical centering can be very tricky, lots of browser quirks to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

vertical-align:middle won't work on div (block element). You can refer [here](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) for details.

If you want to vertical align, I think the only option is using margin/padding with appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` can only be applied to elements with:

- `display:table-cell` in order to vertically align the contents of the element.
- `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` in order to vertically align the element within the text line that contains it

A cheap hack with the latter : http://jsfiddle.net/8bZQS/